# I have implemented a class for serialization using boost libraries but it fails during compilation

Tags: c++

The error I get after compilation: undefined reference to 'boost archive::text_oarchive_impl::text_oarchive_impl(std::ostream&, unsigned int)'
I included the directory and also linked the
system and filesystem .lib files

```
/** Following framework provides a utility to serialize objects using boos serialization libraries **/

#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <fstream>
//#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

static const std::string EXTENSION = "_objects_container";

template <class ObjectName> class Serialization {
protected:
    std::string filename;

    virtual std::string get_object_name() {
        return typeid(ObjectName).name();
    }
    virtual std::string get_file_extension() {
        return ".txt";
    }

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & filename;
    }
public:
    Serialization() {
        filename = get_object_name() + EXTENSION + get_file_extension();
    }
    virtual ~Serialization() {

    }

    //Accessors
    std::string GetFilename() const {return filename;}
    //Mutators
    void SetFilename(std::string chng_name) { filename = chng_name;}

    //APIs
    void WriteToFile(const ObjectName obj) {
        std::ofstream wf(filename.c_str(), std::ios::app);
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(wf);

        oa<<obj;
    }
    void LoadFromFile(ObjectName &obj) {
        std::ifstream rf(filename);
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(rf);

        ia>>obj;
    }
};

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int abc = 10;
    Serialization<int> ss;
    ss.WriteToFile(abc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems to compile but not link properly with the Boost Serialization library. Try adding the appropriate linker option, e.g. `-lboost_serialization`, `-lserialization` or similar?